# Angular 2 router error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I created Angular 2 router module but it doen't work at the moment and I get an error when I want to open link /city 'ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet'

But I can open this link manually

Here is the code of:
Router module

```
import { NgModule }from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {WeatherListComponent} from "../weather-list/weather-list.component";
import {AddedCityComponent} from "../added-city/added-city.component";
import {AppComponent} from "../app.component";


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/weather-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'city', component: AddedCityComponent },
    { path: 'weather-list',  component: WeatherListComponent }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

2) Appmodule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdCardModule, MdInputModule} from '@angular/material';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WeatherListComponent } from './weather-list/weather-list.component';

import { WeatherService } from './service/weather.service';
import { WeatherSearchComponent } from './weather-search/weather-search.component';
import { CloudsComponent } from './clouds/clouds.component';
import { SunComponent } from './sun/sun.component';
import { RainComponent } from './rain/rain.component';
import { AddedCityComponent } from './added-city/added-city.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './service/app.routing';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WeatherListComponent,
    AddedCityComponent,
    WeatherSearchComponent,
    CloudsComponent,
    SunComponent,
    RainComponent


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdInputModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule


  ],
  providers: [
    WeatherService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3) AppComponentHTML

```
<div class="page-wrapper" [ngClass]="{
                                    'sun-background': weatherDesc == 'Clear',
                                    'rain-background': weatherDesc == 'Rain',
                                    'clouds-background': weatherDesc == 'Clouds'
                                      }">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <header>
          <div class="header-wrapper">
            <h3 class=" text-left">Weather App</h3>
            <a routerLink="/city" routerLinkActive="active">cities</a>
            <a routerLink="/weather-list" routerLinkActive="active">weather</a>
            <app-weather-search></app-weather-search>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<app-weather-list (notify)="background($event)"></app-weather-list>-->
  <!--<app-weather-list></app-weather-list>-->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using multiple routing outlets?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'city', component: AddedCityComponent },
    { path: 'weather-list',  component: WeatherListComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/weather-list', pathMatch: 'full'}

  ];
```

and move `appRoutingModule` to the start of the list in the `imports` declaration

Answer (score 0):

i see that you don't have router-outlet in your App component. Try to copy this code in your app.component.html :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

then try to enter to open links.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the leading slashes in the `/weather-list` to `weather-list`. This will make the first path work which might be causing the problem. Just try this out and let me know.

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though your routerLinks are not setup correctly in the component html.

Try changing your link tags from ...

```
<a routerLink="/city" routerLinkActive="active">cities</a>
<a routerLink="/weather-list" routerLinkActive="active">weather</a>
```

To ...

```
<a [routerLink]="['/city']" routerLinkActive="active">
<a [routerLink]="['/weather-list']" routerLinkActive="active">
```

You might also try removing the .forRoot on your routing module import, I am not sure that it is necessary in this case.